# $A \subsetneq B$, $B$ is in a $\sigma$-ring, it doesn't imply $A\in \sigma(R)$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $R$ be a ring and $\sigma(R)$ the ring generated by $R$. Is there an easy counter example to show that a proper subset of $B\in\sigma(R)$ is not in the $\sigma$-ring?

Comment: What kind of rings are you talking about?

Comment: Any ring such that set difference and countable unions are close. Preferably the Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}$ which belong to a $\sigma$-ring. This was mentioned in a comment on a previous question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4488659/mu-measurable-set-in-the-sigma-ring/4488678?noredirect=1#comment9415450_4488678

Comment: Indeed, for the above example, is there a proper subset $A$ of the interval $(a,b)$ such that $A\notin \sigma$?

Comment: As I said in the comments, this should answer your question [Lebesgue measurable set that is not a Borel measurable set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141017/lebesgue-measurable-set-that-is-not-a-borel-measurable-set)